# What to do if how to fix a question about an error comes up being opinion based?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) queue (readers should have some minimal background), I stumbled over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794502/c-how-to-pass-a-name-to-the-constructor-of-base-class).

The answer how to fix the questions primary concern is pretty simple:

> Make the symbols of parameter and member variable unambiguous.

The rest of the question (answers respectively) tends to go into a discussion of how to do that ***the best way***, which is clearly *opinion based*.

Would it be a right action to close vote this question for the above stated reason?

Comment: I think the majority of questions would fall into this... There's often multiple ways of doing things when programming each with their own pros and cons, there's always going to be *some* subjectivity in answers. I don't see this as being opinion based in the slightest.

Comment: @KevinB Fair point. I agree the question doesn't ask for opinions, but the possible answers tend to be.

Comment: amazingly the question was linked on meta for hours and the "thanks" was still there. Well sorry, I had to cut it. I -had- to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no opinion based wording in that question. Answers are going to have an element of opinion no matter what you do, that is allowed. What isn't allowed is asking for opinions. Even then, if the opinion based wording can be removed from a question and you end up with a "How do I do X" question, then you should do that.

I save my "Primarily Opinion Based" close votes for questions that propose one or more things, then ask which one is better, as well as other such questions that cannot be edited into an on-topic question without replacing the entire quest.

Comment: OK! Got it. Though what should we do about all of the opinions that will be expressed in the possibly broad list of upcoming answers? Are these helpful?

Comment: Why should anything be done about them? If they aren't useful downvote them, when applicable delete vote them.

Answer (score 1):

It's important that there be objective criteria by which you can determine if an answer has successfully answered the question.  Questions that don't have this are "Primarily opinion based".

In your example one can objectively state whether the proposed solution fixes the problem or not.

For *every* problem, there is going to be some level of subjectivity in determining not *if* an answer answers the question, but *how well* it answers it.  It will *always* be a matter of opinion which of two correct answers is *better*.  This question is not at all unique in that regard.  This is entirely expect, and entirely appropriate.